# How to take a snapshot of a particular Jenkins Build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have my application running as a Jenkins nightly build. During release I make sure all the test cases pass. How do I preserve a snapshot of the workspace just before every release? Can I store it in Jenkins as a build snapshot result? Please let me know.

Thanks
Jeevan

Answer (score 1):

You could ZIP or TAR up the contents of the workspace at the beginning of the build, and then use the "Archive the artifacts" post build step to save the archive with the release build.

Comment: This works fine. But is there a way to enable this only for few particular build not every nightly builds. I need to do this only when I give release of a product. Is there a switch in Jenkins to enable and disable it?